# Magento2 : How to connect third party ERP system with Magento system

Tags: magento2, api, third-party-library

I'm working on Mageno2 module, which is connect to **Infor ERP system**.

How to get data from Infor to Magento system or Magento to Infor system?

Any documents or third party extension available for it.

If anyone have knowledge about it, please share your thought on it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It can be done by creating custom api endpoint to both platform

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260823/how-to-connect-third-party-service-like-erp-system-in-magento-2